# Xamarin Publishing Failed Signing Failed Android APK

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk, visual-studio-mac

I want to generate an APK for the Android version of my app. I never had a problem doing it on Visual Studio for Mac, but this week started not working anymore.

I get this error after I type my keystore password:

> Signing Failed
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.zip, Version=1.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

[image]

It happens even when I try to resign an older archive that I signed before with the same keystore, but it succeeds when I keep the old signature.

Publishing iOS IPAs works normally.

Anyone has an idea of how to correct it?

---

Publishing Log:

> Begining distribution, 4/10/2018 9:15:49 AM
>
> Channel: Ad Hoc
>
> App Bundle Id: br.com.cartaomagnus.magnusempresario, Version: 2.0.0
>
> Publishing Ad Hoc to /Users/brunoserrano/Downloads/br.com.cartaomagnus.magnusempresario.apk
>
> Signing packages...
>
> Detected signing algorithm as : RSA
>
> ERROR:Signing Failed
>
> ERROR:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>
> File name: 'Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.AndroidPublisher+<>c__DisplayClass59_0.b__1 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task st) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5810/0d8e3f0a/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/Archival/AndroidPublisher.cs:274
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:111
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502
>
> Saving state back to archive
>
> Finshed

Comment: Use the `Help -> Report a Problem` feature in the IDE to report this issue.

Comment: Already did it, waiting for an answer there and maybe a workaround here.

Comment: I would recommend using the target and property `/t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release` in MSBuild for now.

Comment: I generated my signed APK successfully using MSBuild, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile Microsoft and Xamarin team check my report, I could generate my signed APK using MSBuild in Terminal, thanks to @JonDouglas comment.

In the Droid folder of my project, I ran it in Terminal:

`MSBuild "/t:SignAndroidPackage" "/p:Configuration=Release" "/p:AndroidKeyStore=true" "/p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=YourKeyAlias" "/p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=YourKeyStorePassword" "/p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=YourKeyStoreFilename" "/p:AndroidSigningStorePass=YourKeyStorePassword" "YourAppName.csproj"`